# Which statistical test to use for multi-modal and mixed type data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric

I researched for hours but cannot find the direction for the right statistical test to use. Here is the situation for Population A and B:

[image]

When plotting this frequency distribution, it looks like this:
[image]

My observations to this point:
- Shape: Multi-modal
- Data type: Discrete

Additional information:
- N=3 million people 
- n(A)=47,800 and n(B)=37,900 
- Typically amounts are discrete such as: $1,$5,$10, $20 dollars
-The mean of A: $7.11 dollars and B: $7.49 dollars
-The standard deviation of both is the same $8.00

The goal is to compare if the means of the two populations (A and B) differ. This means we need the right statistical test and that is the issue I have. I researched days and cannot find a solution which includes the complexities in my situation.

What is the right test for this? Also, is it recommended to re-arrange the bins where exact $ amounts (5$,10$,20$) are put in range bins to avoid the mix of bins with range and bins without?

Comment: Do you have any information on the actual amount spent in each case, or is the information only available within these categories? If you don't have the actual amount spent in each case, what assumptions did you make about the spending in the continuous groupings (e.g., >1 and <5; >=500) to calculate an overall mean and SD? Also, what are the total numbers in each of groups A and B?

Comment: @EdM Hi, I have no information on actual amount spent in each case. The total number of samples (n) for A and B is the sum of the columns for each (A=44,800 and B=37,900) out of 3mio (N). Also, I did not make any assumptions yet on the behavior within each bin that come with a range. The only information is that amounts are typically discrete such as: 1,5,10,20. I wonder if we can create bins to remove the exact dollar amounts such as: 0-5;5.01−10; 10.01-20$; etc. Would this help in any way?

Comment: Comment moved to answer format to incorporate later information you provided and to allow room for full sentences and a formula. With such large sample sizes the Central Limit theorem implies that the sample means are nearly normally distribution, also (even though the SDs are sample estimates) a t statistic with such large degrees of freedom is nearly normal. // Finally, with your grouped data, it is difficult to use nonparametric tests based on ranks. // Heights of brown and grey bars in your chart differ systematically in height (brown taller) mainly because height represents frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information given, it seems important facts are that $\bar X_2−\bar X_1$=.38 is the difference in sample means, that both sample variances are 8.00 and that sample sizes are around $n_1≈6000,n_2≈5000.$ (It is too bad the data table cuts off what I suppose to be the
actual sample sizes.)

If the facts above are correct, then the two-sample t statistic is $T≈2.5,$ which is larger than 1.96, so that the difference between the sample means is statistically significant at the 5% level. (With such large sample sizes, the t statistic must be nearly distributed as standard normal.)

$$T = \frac{\bar X_2 - \bar X_1}{S\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}}.$$

A major question is whether a difference of 38 cents is of practical importance, even if significant.

*Addendum:* Computation of $T.$ Please check that I have understood all of the quantities correctly.

```
num = 7.49 - 7.11;  num
[1] 0.38
denom = 8*sqrt(1/6000 + 1/5000); denom
[1] 0.1531883
num/denom
[1] 2.480607
```

---

**Addendum from Comments:** On computations of two-sided pooled t test and of one-factor ANOVA with two levels of the factor. Notice that the two P-values (0.03471) are the same.

*Simulate normal data:* Two groups, 20 observations in each.

```
set.seed(2019)
x1 = rnorm(20, 100, 15)
x2 = rnorm(20, 107, 15)
x = c(x1, x2)
g = as.factor(c(rep(1,20), rep(2,20)))
```

*Pooled two-sided t test:*

```
t.test(x ~ g, var.eq=T)

        Two Sample t-test

data:  x by g
t = -2.1903, df = 38, p-value = 0.03471
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -21.5286640  -0.8472255
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       95.94316       107.13111 

qt(.975, 38)
[1] 2.024394   # 5% critical values +/- 2.024
qt(.975, 38)^2
[1] 4.098172   # compare square with ANOVA
(-2.1903)^2   
[1] 4.797414   # square of t stat / compare F

anova(lm(x ~ g))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
g          1 1251.7 1251.70  4.7972 0.03471 *
Residuals 38 9915.1  260.92                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
qf(.95, 1, 38)  # 5% critical value of F test
[1] 4.098172
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the assessment. May I ask (out of curiosity) why a T-test was chosen and not a non-parametric test for example (since data shows not normality)? Does this have to do the CLT? Given your evaluation, can we say that the 38 cents difference is stat. significant, thus both populations behave differently?

Comment: See my new comment beneath the Question. The 38 cent difference is statistically significant, but are you sure such a small difference matters for practical purposes?

Comment: Thank you for all. I just calculated the independent Two sample t-Test to get to the same T value that you have. For some reason, I get T=0.4 and not close to 2.5 which you have. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See addendum. I'm only guessing at sample sizes, which might make a difference.

Comment: @BrueET ah, I see. that's what it was :). I plugged in the sample means A= 4480 and B=3790 VS A=6000 and B=5000 which is the variables you used. So, sorry I didn't catch that. It looks like with the actual sample means I get actually the T-value = 6.9. So, yes it looks as its stat. different. My last question: Why did we not use ANOVA test for example? Why t-test? Was there any evaluation thought process when you decided T test?

Comment: @ee8291 This answer from BruceET is good based on the information you provided, but I still have a question about where you got the values for the means and the standard deviation. If all that you know for a purchase is that it was somewhere between 1 and 5 dollars, what value did you assign to it in calculating the mean and the standard deviation? Did you assign a value of 1, or of 5, or halfway between (e.g., 3) or choose a random value between 1 and 5? What about for purchases that were >500? Or was there a prior calculation of means and standard deviation with the original data now gone?

Comment: @EdM good question.  the values for the means and the standard deviation were provided to me and assumed to be correct.

Comment: @BruceET would you be able to explain why T-Test within all parametric tests and not for example Anova?

Comment: An ANOVA is generally used to look for differences among three or more groups (levels of a factor). If an ANOVA is used to compare only **two** groups, then the F-test is precisely the same as two-sided pooled t test. One rejects in the ANOVA if $F > c,$ where the F-statistic has 1 numerator df and r denominator df. One rejects in the pooled t test if $|T| > \sqrt{c}$ where $T$ has Student's t distribution with r df. Also,  in this case, $T^2 = F.$